# Spark job optimization spark.sql.hive.filesourcePartitionFileCacheSize

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, query-optimization, parquet

Need help in optimizing spark count query on parquet file.

I have parquet files, say on location path_of_old_parquet_file.
At path_of_old_parquet_file I did some transformation to add a new column (account_id) and saved the entire new data set at new location (say path_of_new_parquet_file).

```
spark version 2.3.0.cloudera3
Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_281)
```

Issues:
While running below count query on old location I am getting results in 7 minutes max.
Below is the query, partitions it is creating and the count.

```
spark.read.parquet("path_of_old_parquet_file").count
[Stage 5:==========================>                          (108 + 106) / 214]
[Stage 7:=================================================>  (5327 + 96) / 5604]

count:3450809070
```

Now while running the same query on new data set (only addition of a new column), the time it is taking is more than 40 minutes.
And instead of creating 5604 partition (in case of old location), it is now creating 89355 partitions
And this time I am also getting addition warning message regarding table caching (spark.sql.hive.filesourcePartitionFileCacheSize = 262144000 bytes)

```
spark.read.parquet("<path_of_new_parquet file>").count
21/04/15 09:45:59 WARN datasources.SharedInMemoryCache: Evicting cached table partition metadata from memory due to size constraints (spark.sql.hive.filesourcePartitionFileCacheSize = 262144000 bytes). This may impact query planning performance.
21/04/15 09:52:40 WARN util.Utils: Truncated the string representation of a plan since it was too large. This behavior can be adjusted by setting 'spark.debug.maxToStringFields' in SparkEnv.conf.
[Stage 0:==========================>                          (108 + 109) / 217]
[Stage 3:==================================>              (63690 + 200) / 89355]

Count: 3426213132
```

For both the case I am using below resources. Which I have tried to tweak as well.

```
master yarn
num-executors 50 
executor-cores 5 
driver-memory 50G 
executor-memory 14G
```

I aslo tried by adding below config as well but no luck.

`--conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=2000`

Additional Info:
path_of_new_parquet_file and path_of_old_parquet_file partitioned by date(daily) and source (total 3 source)
Total approx 300 date partitions

```
hdfs dfs -du -h path_of_new_parquet_file
684.2 G  1.3 T  path_of_new_parquet_file

hdfs dfs -du -h path_of_old_parquet_file
562.6 G  1.1 T  path_of_old_parquet_file
```

Can anyone please guide what to do (approach), so that I can bring back the count query time to close to old time.

Please note: Right now I don't have the access to Spark webUI server to check on stats. I am working on it.

Comment: if its 300 partitions on date make it shuffle partitions 300 * 2.5 shuffle partitions and size. i.e.,   --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=750  Now try and check

Comment: Not working. Each of my executor is allotted 14 GB in Spark UI.
Each partition itself is big.